# How can I use the window.close() inside a href?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I use window.close() inside

Im trying to add the window.close() inside my href. This is my code for that matter

```
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>".sprintf("%s", $col2)."</th>";
    echo "<th>".sprintf("%s", $col3)."</th>";
    echo "<th>".sprintf("%s", $col4)."</th>";
    echo "<th>".sprintf("%s", $col18)."</th>";
    echo "<th>".sprintf("%s", $col19)."</th>";
    echo "<th><a target='_blank' href='review.php?id=$col1'>Click</a></th>";
    echo '</tr>';
  }
```

im trying to add the window.close() in this line

```
echo "<th><a target='_blank' href='review.php?id=$col1'>Click</a></th>";
```

i hope someone can help. thank you

Comment: Try this `<a href="javascript:window.close();">Close Window</a>`

Comment: where can I add my href='review.php?id=$col1'

Comment: you are asking to add the `window.close` at the `href` so i did it. You can also add this in `onclick="javascript:window.close();"`

Comment: but how can I add the code to direct to the next page. What im really trying to do is, when I click the button to the next page, the first page will close

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this.

```
<a href="javascript:window.close();">Close Window</a>
```

In your case:

```
echo '<th><a target="_blank" href="javascript:window.close();">Click</a></th>';
```

Comment: where can I add my href='review.php?id=$col1'

Comment: this gives me an error. unexpected javascrip

echo "<th><a href='javascript:window.close();'>Close Window</a></th>";

im using double quotation in my <th> tag and when I use \ beside the double quotation nothing happened.

Comment: @aronpascua, look at the link: [Window/close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close), i will update with in sometime.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a function onclick button:

```
function close_window() {
  if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
    close();
  }
}
```

If you want to use only html then you can do this:

```
<a href="javascript:close_window();">close</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" onclick="close_window();return false;">close</a>
```

To avert the default behavior for the event `return false` is used. The browser will attempt to open that URL otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are wanting to open a new tab/window and close the current one, you will want to start a timeout for the window.close function.

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" onClick="javascript: setTimeout(window.close, 10);">Close Me</a>
```

Comment: can I use single quotation instead of double quotation in this code?

from:
<a href="#" onclick="OpenNewCloseCurrent('www.google.com');">Close Me</a>

to: 
<a href='#' onclick='OpenNewCloseCurrent('www.google.com');'>Close Me</a>

will the code still run?

Comment: Go with @GrantMooney, I think he will help you more.

Comment: is there a way to use double quotation? because when i use double quotation i get an error. and when i use single quotation the javascript does not run

Comment: Do you mean single quotation?

Comment: yes. i trying to get the id of the specific data and will proceed to next page

Comment: Assuming you are using the updated code, your link will look something like `<a href="review.php?id=$col1" target="_blank" onClick="javascript: setTimeout(window.close, 10);">Close Me</a>` (based on the link you provided)

Comment: If you need to escape the double quotation marks, use `\"` instead of `"`

Comment: this is what my codes look like echo `"<th><a href=\"review.php?id=$col1\" target=\"_blank\" onClick=\"javascript: setTimeout(window.close, 0);\">Close Me</a></th>";` but still not working. it directed me to another page but the first page is not closing

Comment: Make sure your timeout is set to at least 1 ms, 10 is ideal (it works better with chrome)